# ActiveRecord - NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

These AREL queries do not work in Rails 3. Can someone help me decipher this error?

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0xabf6f44>):
  app/controllers/admin_controller.rb:206:in `save_user'
```

**All of these cause the same error as shown above**

```
  @existing = Privilege.find(:first, :conditions => "b2b_user_id = #{@user.id} AND vendor_id = #{@vendor_id}")

  @existing = Privilege.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM b2b_privileges WHERE b2b_user_id = ? AND vendor_id = ? LIMIT 1",@user.id,@vendor_id)

  @existing = Privilege.where(:b2b_user_id => @user.id, :vendor_id => @vendor_id)
```

But when I change this:

```
@user = B2bUser.where("id = ?",params[:id])
```

To this:

```
@user = B2bUser.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

The queries work. Why?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're getting whn using method "where" is just a relation, think of it like a query that is still not executed, then you have to call a method to retrieve data eg: first, all, last, to_a, etc

```
@user = B2bUser.where("id = ?",params[:id]) #this is just an active record relation
@user = B2bUser.where("id = ?",params[:id]).first #this is your object
```

Read a little about relations, they're really interesting
[relations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html)